# Tag synonym request: REPL

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I don't have enough reputation to do it myself, so please do.

I think [repl](/questions/tagged/repl) - as a standard and comfortable shortcut abbreviation - should be marked as synonym for fully spelled term [read-eval-print-loop](/questions/tagged/read-eval-print-loop).

Or vice versa, but former is better to me.

So, please, open https://stackoverflow.com/tags/read-eval-print-loop/synonyms
and add https://stackoverflow.com/tags/repl to it.

Also copy tag-wiki from REPL to read-eval-print-loop. *though hopefully SO engine can do it automagically when synonyms registered*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done.  I've moved the tag wiki from [repl](/questions/tagged/repl) and moved it to [read-eval-print-loop](/questions/tagged/read-eval-print-loop), as well as merged the former into the latter.

I've reworked [the wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/read-eval-print-loop/info) for the latter a little to reverse the acronym and the expansion of the acronym as well.